# Biblatex: Title of crossref not shown in @INREFERENCE entry

Tags: biblatex

I am using a bibfile with an @INREFERENCE entry. Surprisingly when cited the title of the lexicon is not shown.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=footnote-dw, citestyle=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
    The title of the encyclopedia is missing!\footcite{Article}
\end{document}
```

where the content of bibliography.bib is:

```
@BOOK{Encyclopedia,
    TITLE       = {Some Encyclopedia},
    EDITOR      = {Editor, Just An},
}

@INREFERENCE{Article,
    AUTHOR      = {Scientist, Fancy},
    TITLE       = {Just some article},
    CROSSREF    = {Encyclopedia},
}
```

The resulting footnote looks like:

```
Fancy Scientist: art. "Just some article". In: Just An Editor (ed.).
```

Expected / desired output would be

```
Fancy Scientist: art. "Just some article". In: Some encyclopedia, Just An Editor (ed.).
```

It does not seem to depend on the citestyle (I checked verbose, verbose-ibid, authortitle, authoryear, authortitle-dw and authoryear-dw)

I cannot use @INBOOK as a workaround since I need the @INREFERENCE-entries marked by an "art." which I obtain with citesteyle footnote-dw

Answer (score 1):

Arrgh. After hours of searching the idea came to me just after posting the question here: The title of the crossrefed encyclopedia has to be given by

```
BOOKTITLE = {Some encyclopedia},
```

But anyway: Strange that the problem does not occur when using @INBOOK instead of @INREFERENCE

Comment: The problem is that, fundamentally, should be of type `@reference` (or `@incollection`, in most styles the former is an alias of the latter); naturally `@inreference`s can only occur in `@reference`s. The types have to match: Either `@inbook in a `@book`, or` or `@inreference` in a `@reference`.